# Speaker diarization tool for 3+ participants

Tags: speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services, speaker

We have a video library 3k+ files mostly tech conference and townhalls, mono channel, with 1-10 speakers. Now we would like to run the speaker diarization process.
We tried to use Batch transcription REST API
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/cognitive-services/Speech-Service/batch-transcription.md
but it looks like it has a limitation of 2 speakers only.
We also investigated the Conversation Transcription service https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/conversation-transcription
but it expects Multi-channel audio stream input.

Would you please recommend what Cognitive service tool we can use, if any, to resolve our task?

Thanks!

Comment: This is an [off-topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "4. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam." Maybe see https://superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed batch processing is currently limited to diarization for 2 people only. We expect in November/December to have a new diarization provider utilized in batch that will support 10 speakers on a mono input audio stream.

I don't know any cognitive services tool that would match your requirements right now.

thx
Wolfgang